# Creating a linked list to implement a queue

Tags: c, linked-list

I am newbie in C and I am trying to write a linked list in which each node simply contains an int. The definition of the structure is ok, but I also want to write methods to update this linked list (add element at the tail and delete the head element). (I want to be able to read the most recently added element)

I wrote the functions below, but I don't know where the free should take place and how to implement it. Could anyone help me with this?

```
typedef struct Node{
    Node next = NULL;
    int number;
} Node;

void add_node(Node *LL,int val){ 
    // add node to the end of the linked list
    new_node = (struct Node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->number = val;
    Node n = *LL;
    while (n.next != NULL){
        n = n.next;
    }
    n.next = new_node;
}

void delete_head(Node *LL){
     // update the head
    *LL = LL->next;
    //free?
}

void update_LL(*LL,int val){
    add_node(*LL,val);
    delete_head(*LL);
}
```

Comment: `Node next = NULL;` --> `struct Node *next;` in C.

Comment: As written, there is no way to update the head from within `delete_head`: it is passed a pointer to the head node, but has no idea where that value is stored, and thus cannot update it.  You can (as many have explained) delete that node, but whatever is keeping track of the head needs to be updated to the new head.

Answer (score 1):

I rename your data structure this way:

```
struct pointer
            {
            int field; 

            struct pointer *link; 
            };
typedef struct pointer cell;
```

Then we can use this function for your need:

```
void ad_an_element_at_the_end_of_the_list()
         {
         cell *p=NULL;
         cell *ptr=head;

         int value;

         cout<<" Integer number to insert at the end of the list: ";
         cin>>value;
         p=(cell*)malloc(sizeof(cell));
         p->field=value;
         p->link=NULL;
         if(ptr==NULL) 
            {
            ptr=p;
            head=ptr;

            }else
                {
                if(ptr->link==NULL)  t
                  {
                  ptr->link=p;
                  head=ptr;

                  }else
                     {
                      while(ptr->link!=NULL) 
                        {
                        ptr=ptr->link;
                        }
                     ptr->link=p;

                    }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `*LL = LL->next;` for `Node *nextNode = LL->next;`.
Then you can call `free(LL)` followed by `LL = nextNode`.

```
void delete_head(Node *LL){
    Node *nextNode = LL->next;
    free(LL);
    LL = nextNode;
}
```

This then frees the `Node` at the head and moves the pointer to the next one in the Linked List.

Comment: Since `LL` is effectively a local variable, this will *not* move the head.

Comment: @ScottHunter It's been a while since I've used C but would this be solved by passing a reference (using the `&` symbol before the variable, when passing it to the function)?

Comment: I think you should review how "passing by reference" and "passing by value" is done. If a pointer is passed as an argument it points to a memory location, whatever operations are performed on that memory location by whomever function in whichever scope are permanent.

Comment: @MurtazaZaidi ^ This was my original understanding

Comment: @AeroX: No; then you'd be passing a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-Node, and have a type mismatch.  But if `LL` were declared as `Node **LL`, and the code referred to `*LL` for the pointer to the `Node`, then that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a duplicate of this question [LinkedList - How to free the memory allocated using malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025328/linkedlist-how-to-free-the-memory-allocated-using-malloc)

Basically you have to store the pointer to the node you want to delete otherwise you will leak that memory as there will be no reference to that memory location anywhere in your code.

try this in your delete_head function:

Node *temp = LL;

*LL = LL->next;

free(LL);

Hope this helps!

Comment: `temp` and `*LL` don't have the same type; for that matter, neither do `*LL` and `LL->next`.

Comment: Don't trust me; ask a compiler.

Comment: Ok, since it was declared as a Node in the Node class not a node pointer I got things mixed up. Assuming that it is changed to a Node pointer so it can compile, this solution should work

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your link to node which is next before you delete current node. Otherwise you won't be able to refer any node of your linkedlist. Now when you have backed up your link to next node, you can free current node pointed by LL, and then assign LL pointer to next node which you had earlier backed up in temp pointer.

```
Node *temp = LL->next;
free(LL);
LL = temp;
```

Comment: Since `LL` is effectively a local variable, this will *not* move the head.

Comment: @ScottHunter please review this http://www.nongnu.org/c-prog-book/online/x641.html

Comment: If a pointer is passed as an argument it points to a memory location, whatever operations are performed on that memory location by whomever function in whichever scope are permanent.

Comment: But the pointer being passed points to a Node, so you can make changes to that Node, but not the original variable pointing to it (which is what head is).  And to do *that*, you'd need to make an assignment to `*LL`; changes to `LL` from within this function have *no* effect outside of the function.

Comment: I think you need to review your knowledge of pointers. If p is a pointer, it points to some memory location, we use p to make changes in that memory location directly. Now that change is permanent. If I free that memory location all data which was stored there is now lost, if I update value at that location, new value would be permanent, not specific to scope of function.

Comment: Pointers and Variables are two different things. Changes made to variables are dependent on scope in which those changes were made. Any change made via pointer is persistent in all scopes.

Comment: So if the call was `delete_head(&x)`, where `x` is declared as a `Node`, what exactly would `LL = temp` within the function change?

Comment: x is pointer to node, we pass address of this pointer to LL, now LL is pointing to same node which x was pointing. You get it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62619/discussion-between-scott-hunter-and-murtaza-zaidi).